# How to set the Web application context in Thorntail?

Tags: thorntail

I'm looking for a way to customize the Web application name (so to change the Web context accordingly) in Thorntail. I assume that it can be done through the thorntail's maven plugin but I cannot find which is the property to set for it.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the context is `/`, which should be what you want most of the time. To customize it, you can use one of the following options:

1) Pass the `thorntail.context.path` system property when starting the uberjar: `java -jar my-app-thorntail.jar -Dthorntail.context.path=my-context`.

2) If you use `project-defaults.yml`, you can configure it there:

```
thorntail:
  context:
    path: my-context
```

3) Create a file `WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml` with this content:

```
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>my-context</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

(Under the hood, options 1 and 2 are actually transformed to 3, but you don't have to care.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Right now I've found in one of the examples the project-defaults.yml way to configure it. I wasn't aware of the System property which is perfect to avoid changing the application. Thanks